# For loop in C and how it works?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, conditional-statements

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int i, j;

    for (i = 2; i < 20; i++) {
        for (j = 2; j <= (i/j); j++) {
            if (!(i%j)) break;
        }
        if (j > (i/j)) printf("%d\n", i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am a Beginner at C and trying to understand how the for loop works. My question is at the 4th iteration, the condition in the nested loop will return `TRUE`

```
(j < (i/j))    // 2 <= 4/2
```

and the first `if` statement will also return `TRUE` because of `NOT` operator

```
(!(i%j));    // 4/2 = !(0)
```

so now the value of `j = 3` because of incrementation, but why the second `if` statement did not print the output if it is `TRUE`?

```
(j > (i/j));    // 3 > 4/3
```

Comment: `My question is at the 4TH loop`  where is that?

Comment: just imagine that the loop is now at 4th loop .

Comment: did you mean iteration?

Comment: sorry . don't know gow to speak english well .

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger and step through the code while it's running to see exactly what it does. i.e. empower yourself to answer your own questions of this level.

Comment: Ah . i don't have that one but i will try to download it later. thanks ..

Comment: If you don't have (or don't use) a debugger, you can answer your questions by adding `printf` statements to your code. For example: `printf("Debugging: i = %d, j = %d\n", i, j)`. If you put these statements in correct places in your code, it will be easy to track its execution.

Comment: Ah. I'm using mingw is it compatible with that? thanks . I'll search how that works :)

Answer (score 4):

You're breaking out of the loop before j is incremented, so j is still 2, not 3

Answer (score 3):

A break statement ends its nearest enclosing loop prematurely. Everything after it (and that includes the third statement of the `for` loop), will not occur.

So `j` is still 2 when the condition for printing is checked, like **Mark** answered.

Comment: and about at the 9th iteration, how the second if statement returns TRUE?
thanks .

Comment: @DisplayName You mean when `i` is `9`, or `10`? (since you start from `2` it isn't clear what the ninth iteration is)

Comment: @DisplayName, running your code doesn't print `9` or `10` http://ideone.com/OmXHvp  It only prints primes.